# Can't understand why this cast is invalid

Tags: dart

I am a bit confused about why this casting am I performing is throwing an exception. This is the code:

```
var myJson = json.decode(response.body);
List<Map<String,dynamic>> childrenJson = myJson['children'] as List<Map<String,dynamic>>;
```

But this works as expected:

```
var myJson = json.decode(response.body);
    List<dynamic> childrenJson = myJson['children'];
    Map<String, dynamic> item = childrenJson[0];
```

If the children entry is a list of maps of (String, dynamic) why am I not able to cast it that way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to use:

```
var childrenJson = List.cast<Map<String,dynamic>>(myJson['children]);
```

which should throw an exception at runtime if any of the children cannot be casted.  The "as" is more of a compile-time thing, and can only be used if the compiler can infer that as a type.